# Python selenium can't locate element since it is not in the source code

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the date that is highlighted in the calendar from https://web.archive.org/web/20110101000000*/area51.stackexchange.com

I can see the "calendar-day" class in chrome inspector but it is not displayed in the source code.
[image: chrome inspector]
I have also tried to locate other class elements such as "month-week" but failed. Can anyone help me to diagnose what the problem is? I have looked into ShadowDOM but it seems not to be the issue here (I might be wrong though).

Furthermore, I am also trying to get the url "/web/20110430/area51.stackexchange.com" but don't know how to locate by class, tag name, css or Xpath.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20110101000000*/area51.stackexchange.com")
element=driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendar-day")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is missing a ".

Comment: Also the class name has a space at the end.

Comment: @arundeepchohan, thanks, fixed those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wait for the div element of calender to come up and print it. Your class name had an extra space as well as taking some time after a page loads.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'calendar-day')]")))
print(element.text)
```

Outputs 11

To grab multiple

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'calendar-day')]")))
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Outputs
11
30
7
16
18
10
11
7
12

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks! The waiting works. The output 11 is the first occurrence under class name "calendar-day ". I also tried find_element_by_class_name after waiting but only get the first occurrence. Do you know how to capture all the cases? Let me know if I should post a new question about this.

Comment: Check mark mine as correct. Also added the grabbing multiples.

Answer (score 1):

The page you are using is taking a while to load, so it will be better if you introduce some explicit wait before extracting.

A sample script can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20110101000000*/area51.stackexchange.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "calendar-day ")))
print(element.text)

driver.quit()
```

To extract multiple element just need to add/change `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "calendar-day ")))`

So updated sample script can be

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20110101000000*/area51.stackexchange.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "calendar-day ")))`

for el in element:
    print(el.text)
    
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! The waiting works. However, it only returns first occurrence, which is 11. There are multiple cases under class name "calendar-day ". I also tried find_element_by_class_name after waiting to capture all cases. Do you know how to capture all the cases? Let me know if I should post a new question about this.